# Deploy Google Cloud - Java 8

Tags: spring-boot, rest, java-8, google-cloud-platform, devops

No estoy pudiendo deployar y hacer funcionar el siguiente código en Google Cloud:
https://github.com/shulians/wather-api

Cuando deployo el servicio, que en proceso y por lo qué veo en los logs ejecuta varias veces el check readness y liveness.

Estoy ejecutando:

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

> Error: GCLOUD:
> .failed.
> [INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>20
> 23-11-06T05:03:04.470Z2481.xw.2: Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.